# Can't translate kartik/datecontrol/DateControl

Tags: yii2, localization, internationalization, yii2-basic-app, kartik-v

I have this Yii application (started from Yii basic template) which I'm trying to translate. The problem is, when I switch from English to Serbian, \kartik\datecontrol\DateControl gets translated wrongly (it gets translated to Serbian, but Cyrillic instead of Latin). Naturally, I found the translation file (vendor/kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol/locales/sr/dateSettings.php) and changed translations, but only display of date changed to Latin. I print_r-ed the location of translation files in DateControl class and it gave me the above file, so I think I got that one correct.

When I click on date picker, nothing changed. Next I went to datepicker component (vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker/messages/sr/kvdate.php) and changed translations there, but again nothing changed. I tried even datetimepicker and timepicker, but again no luck.

Now it's driving me crazy, I have no idea where else to look to translate those strings.

Comment: you might try adding an issue to the github repo for kartik/datecontrol

Comment: Thank you, will try